# Loop for char not working

Tags: c#, loops

So, I am attempting to make a loop where if someone enters a char it will execute. If it is wrong it will will display not an option. If I put an `Else {Console.WriteLine("Not an option")` at the end of the the "end" after my Array() method, it doesn't work either. 
So, I am not completely sure of what I am doing. Does this even require a loop? As I would imagine it does to work? Any suggestions would be wonderful.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string _a = "";
        constructor dick = new constructor();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter C for constructor, M for method, A for an array...");
        Console.WriteLine("Please reference source code to have full details and understanding...");
        while (_a.ToUpper() == "C" || "M" || "A")
        {
            _a = Console.ReadLine();
            if (_a.ToUpper() == "C")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(dick.a);
            }
            if (_a.ToUpper() == "M")
            {
                Shit();
            }
            if (_a.ToUpper() == "A")
            {
                Array();
            }
        }
    }

    public class constructor
    {
        public string a = "This is a constructor!";
    }
    static public void Shit()
    {
        string b = "This is a method!";
        Console.WriteLine(b);
    }
    static public void Array()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nHow large of an array?\n");
        string sSize = Console.ReadLine();
        int arraySize = Convert.ToInt32(sSize);
        int[] size = new int[arraySize];
        Random rd = new Random();
        Console.WriteLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
        {
            size[i] = rd.Next(arraySize);

            Console.WriteLine(size[i].ToString());
        }

    }

}
}
```

Comment: I suggest you name your objects in a more appropriate way.

Comment: You might want to try it with a `switch` statement, breaking after each case. As it is, you execute all of the `if`s, even if the first one matches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of this:

```
while (_a.ToUpper() == "C" || "M" || "A")
```

Define a bool variable and:

```
bool control = true;

while (control)
{
    _a = Console.ReadKey();
    var character = _a.KeyChar.ToString().ToUpper();
    switch (character)
        {
            case "C":
                Console.WriteLine(dick.a);
                control = false;
                break;
            case "M":
                 control = false; 
                 Shit();
                break;
            case "A":
                 control = false;
                 Array();
                 break;
            default:
               Console.WriteLine("You entered wrong character");
               break;
        }
}
```

If you want to force user to enter a correct  character, yes you need a loop.And use [`Console.ReadKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/471w8d85%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of `Console.ReadLine` if the input is just one character

Comment: So would it be an else if I wanted it to display to the user a response if they entered a wrong char? Such as if someone entered B, to let them know that is incorrect.

Comment: Completely understood now. I wrote this really quickly. Was angry hence the vulgarity in the code. Is there a way to do this besides the case switch statements or is this ideally what something such as this was designed for?

Comment: yes,switch case is ideal to do this and more appropriate than if-else if statements.